# Error when trying to add Fire Base unity SDK to unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

This is the error I get when I add the SDK:

```
Assembly 'Assets/Firebase/Editor/Firebase.Editor.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.

Assembly 'Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/1.2.174/Google.IOSResolver.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
```

I first added an older version of the SDK then realized that there was a newer version but when I used the newer version unity refused to install the package. Also, the firebase app page only has android and ios if there's an explanation for that please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

On which platform? if it's android, simply disable validation in this file's inspector. You don't need iOS extension for Android platform.

Comment: In the unity inspector?

Comment: Yes, if you click on the error, it will take you to the file. Perform the said task in its inspector.

Comment: doesn't work if the file is managed through UPM - Unity has a flag to search for iOS Build support, install it, enable, then disable it. I closed it with the answer